# call json data in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, mocking

I want to mock the data in json local files which later will be replaced Restful webservice.But i dont know how to set them up.I am using jquery in aptana studio,also i am familliar with mockjax(as mocking framework).Where do i place the json file in aptana studio?In other words all i know is to call $.ajax() but i dont know where to place the json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you just want a placeholder json file in the root of your application file for testing purposes? Sure, no problem.

Just stick any .js file in the same folder as your .html file (for now -- you can move it around later if you want). The .js file can contain some simple JSON object:

**myjson.js** (stolen from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example))

```
{
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Smith",
     "age": 25,
     "address":
     {
         "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
         "city": "New York",
         "state": "NY",
         "postalCode": "10021"
     },
     "phoneNumber":
     [
         {
           "type": "home",
           "number": "212 555-1234"
         },
         {
           "type": "fax",
           "number": "646 555-4567"
         }
     ]
 }
```

Then, in your HTML file, you will use jQuery's handy `get` method to 'get' the js file:

**test.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Blah</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $.get("myjson.js", function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
    });
    </script>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Once you're ready to use real JSON data, you can change the first parameter of the `get` function from 'myjson.js' to whatever URL you're actually querying.

Answer (score 0):

i usually place it in the same page that it will be used and keep it on the bottom. you can have it on an external page its up to you. but the page that you will be calling whether its a php or asp etc. needs to be in a seperate file. it wont work if you havae it on the same page.

here is an example of what i mean.

i place these on the verry bottom of the page right before the body tag so that it will work 100%.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.get("ajax.php", { id: hash },
 function(out)
 {
    myvariable = out.myoutput;
}, "json");

</script>
```

and the call file ajax.php is in a seperate file and does what i need it to do and the output from the php goes to out.myoutput . i can either print this or store it in a variable as i have.

let me know if i make sense